# iOS11 - Can't hide status bar

Tags: swift, statusbar, ios11

After upgrading to iOS 11 / Xcode9, the status bar is not longer being hidden.

I have "View Controller-Based Status Bar Appearance" set to "YES" in info.plist, and also:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

According to the debugger, `prefersStatusBarHidden` *is* called, but is not having any effect.

Is this a bug? Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Do you want to hide the status bar in all your view controllers everywhere in your app or in only one view controller ?

Comment: call setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

Comment: if still not work then pls try toVC.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true

Comment: Hmm that sounds like a bug though, I just tried and it work just fine on my side. Just try double-check that the key "View controller-based status bar appearance" is properly spelled, and that its value is "YES", then just try cleaning your project (CMD+SHIFT+K) and cleaning your DerivedData folder, and re-open the project again to see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same thing using [STPopUpPreview](https://github.com/kevin0571/STPopupPreview). I had to set `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true` on my preview view controller. Good luck!